# OpenCL and OpenGL group sharing with Apple software renderer

Tags: macos, opengl, opencl, gpgpu, core-image

I have successfully shared a GPU-based OpenGL context with OpenCL (using `CL_CONTEXT_PROPERTY_USE_CGL_SHAREGROUP_APPLE` when creating the OpenCL context).

However if the OpenGL context is software-based (created with `kCGLPFARendererID, kCGLRendererGenericFloatID`), then OpenCL context creation failed with error CL_INVALID_DEVICE (-33).

Is it possible to group-share a CPU-based OpenCL context with a CPU based OpenGL context?

If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a SDK/ Driver specific problem. So you should try to ask this question in a developer forum of the hardware you are trying to use.

For example you can register without problems at this page for amd related stuff:

 http://devgurus.amd.com/welcome 
There you get answers also from AMD interal developers like driver developer. I think they could tell you if it is possible or not.

For the Intel side of live you should try this place:

 http://software.intel.com/de-de/forums/intel-opencl-sdk 
But there i can't tell you how likely the internal developers try to answer.

Comment: As far as I understand Apple writes the OpenCL and OpenGL implementation on their platform, so Intel has nothing to do with that.